# AbstractSecurityInterceptor must provide a non-null AccessDecisionManager

Tags: spring-security

Since upgrade of Spring Security to `5.6.2` I have issues running my application as I keep getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AbstractSecurityInterceptor must provide a non-null AccessDecisionManager
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.<init>(DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.java:54) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.getRequestMatcherPrivilegeEvaluatorsEntry(WebSecurity.java:338) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:305) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:90) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:305) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
```

Until now I did not need the `AccessDecisionManager` bean and everything worked like a charm like this:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
open class OpenApiSecurityConfig() : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/docs")
            .and()
            .addFilter(OpenApiFilter(authService))
    }

    open class OpenApiFilter(private val authService: AuthService) : FilterSecurityInterceptor() {
        override fun doFilter(request: ServletRequest, response: ServletResponse, chain: FilterChain) {
            if (userAuthorized()) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response)
            } else {
                throw AccessDeniedException("Forbidden.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I guess this is just a some kind of new requirement. I added the configuration as:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@Import(AccessManager::class)
@EnableWebSecurity
open class OpenApiSecurityConfig() : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() { … }
… 
@Configuration
open class AccessManager : AccessDecisionManager {
    override fun decide(authentication: Authentication, `object`: Any?, configAttributes: MutableCollection<ConfigAttribute>?) {}
    override fun supports(attribute: ConfigAttribute?): Boolean = false
    override fun supports(clazz: Class<*>?): Boolean = false
}
```

However with no effect.

1. Is it possible to avoid the need for `AccessManager`?
2. What is the correct way of instantiating it?

Comment: This issue stems from creating a custom `FilterSecurityInterceptor`. This filter is not meant to be replaced in the filter chain. It would be best to create a different type of custom filter and insert it before the `FilterSecurityInterceptor`. For example, it could extend `OncePerRequestFilter` and instead of throwing an `AccessDeniedException` if the user is unauthorized it could simply return.

Comment: That worked! If you post it as an answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue stems from creating a custom `FilterSecurityInterceptor`.
This filter is not meant to be replaced in the filter chain.
It would be best to create a different type of custom filter and insert it before the `FilterSecurityInterceptor`. For example, it could extend `OncePerRequestFilter` and instead of throwing an `AccessDeniedException` if the user is unauthorized it could simply return.